# Creating a workflow that only runs for certain Opportunity Record Types

Tags: workflow

In trying to create a workflow rule to run when an Opportunity is closed won if one field is not blank and the record type is a certain Opportunity type, I am getting stuck on the last portion of the formula.  I can successfully write the rule for closed won and the field value not being blank:

```
AND
(
  (ISPICKVAL(StageName,"Closed Won")),
  (NOT(ISBLANK(CUSTOM_FIELD__c)))
)
```

But when I try to apply this only to certain opportunity types and use the RecordTypeId, the rule doesn't fire.

```
AND
(
  (ISPICKVAL(StageName , "Closed Won")) ,
  (NOT( ISBLANK( CUSTOM_FIELD__c ))),

  OR
  (
    RecordTypeId="01290000000OCMSAA4",
    RecordTypeId="01290000000OeQgAAK", 
    RecordTypeId="01290000000OmKlAAK", 
    RecordTypeId="01290000000Oa2bAAC"
  )    
)
```

Am I missing something obvious or going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Try using RecordType.DeveloperName and don't hard code ID's. It is not best practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
AND
(
  (ISPICKVAL(StageName , "Closed Won")) ,
  (NOT( ISBLANK( CUSTOM_FIELD__c ))),
  OR(
     RecordType.DeveloperName = 'NAME_OF_RECORD_TYPE_1',
     RecordType.DeveloperName = 'NAME_OF_RECORD_TYPE_2'
    )
)
```